# How to obtain a 3 months before today date and convert it to dd.mm.yyyy format in VBA

Tags: xml, vba, date

Hi I would like to get the Today() date, make it 3 months earlier.

Then, I would like to convert it from dd-mm-yyyy to dd.mm.yyyy and save it in a String variable.

Comment: Where is your code, and what doesn't work?  VBA has numerous date functions that should make this trivial to do.

Comment: Have you checked the methods of the Datetime Variable returned by Today? There should be a Methode like addMonths which also Accepts negative values. It will Return the new Datetime. For String Conversion Check the Arguments you can pass to the tostring Method of Datetime.

Comment: AddMonths Function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmonths%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Datetime.ToString Arguments: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Sub OldDateConversion
    TodayDate = Date 
    OldDate = DateAdd("m", -3, TodayDate) 
    FormatedOldDate = Format(OldDate, "dd.mm.yyyy")
      'Results in 26.10.2014'
End Sub
```